# Django_rest_framework hyper Linked identity

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

thanks for your time.

i've written some views in rest framework although aint beeing able to set the links for the 'player-detail' and 'event-detail' on url field even the view name(urls.py) beeing right.

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns



urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('player_list/', views.player_list, name='player_list'),
    path('event_list/', views.event_list, name='event_list'),
    path('player_detail/<int:id>/', views.player_detail, name='player-detail'),
    path('event_detail/<int:id>/', views.event_detail, name='event-detail'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    #class based#
    path('player_list_class/', views.PlayerList.as_view(), name='player-list'),
    path('player_detail_class/', views.PlayerDetail.as_view(), name='player-detail'),
    path('event_list_class/', views.EventList.as_view(), name='event_list'),
    path('event_detail_class/', views.EventDetail.as_view(), name='event_detail'),

]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

serializers.py:

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Player, Event



class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['id','url',  'player_id', 'name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'team']
        
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id','url', 'noc', 'games', 'year', 'city', 'season', 'sport']
```

models.py:

```
  
    
class Player (models.Model):
    player_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=sex_choices)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    height = models.FloatField(null=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.player_id, self.name)
    
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        o1 = Player.objects.filter(player_id=self.player_id, age=self.age)
        if o1.exists():
            raise ValidationError('Player already in')
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    
class Event(models.Model):
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events')
    noc = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    games = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=season_choices)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    medal = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.games, self.season)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def player_list(request, format=None):
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = Player.objects.all()
        seri = PlayerSerializer(query, many=True, context = {'request':request})
        return Response(seri.data)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        seri = PlayerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if seri.is_valid():
            seri.save()
            return Response(seri.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(seri.errors, status=400)

   
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@csrf_exempt   
def event_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = Event.objects.all()
        seri = EventSerializer(query, many=True, context = {'request':request})
        return Response(seri.data)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        seri = EventSerializer(data=data)
        if seri.is_valid():
            seri.save()
            return Response(seri.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(seri.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@csrf_exempt
def player_detail(request, id):
    try:
        obj = Player.objects.get(id=id)
    except Player.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        seri = PlayerSerializer(obj, context={'request': request})
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=seri.data)
    
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        seri = PlayerSerializer(obj, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if seri.is_valid():
            seri.save()
            return Response(seri.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        else:
            return Response(seri.errors, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
        
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        obj.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
    
@csrf_exempt      
def event_detail(request, id):
    try:
        obj = Event.objects.get(id=id)
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        seri = EventSerializer(obj, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        return Response(seri.data)
    
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        seri = EventSerializer(obj, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if seri.is_valid():
            seri.save()
            return Response(data=seri.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        else:
            return Response(seri.errors, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
        
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        obj.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

i've tried with class based, generic based, but still don't know why in this project isn't working.

error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /winners/player_list/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "player-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes in your `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Player, Event



class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['id','url',  'player_id', 'name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'team']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'player-detail', 'lookup_field': 'id'},
        }
        
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id','url', 'noc', 'games', 'year', 'city', 'season', 'sport']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'event-detail', 'lookup_field': 'id'},
        }
```

From the [Django Rest Framework documentation on HyperlinkModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined):

> By default hyperlinks are expected to correspond to a view name that matches the style '{model_name}-detail', and looks up the instance by a pk keyword argument. You can override a URL field view name and lookup field by using either, or both of, the view_name and lookup_field options in the extra_kwargs setting...

The problem basically was your primary_key column was named `id` but the default DRF behavior is to use `pk` for the `lookup_field`.